# How to check if user exists with Slack web api

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I just started learning about making Slack apps, and I'm trying to verify that a parameter passed for my command is a valid user. I've tried using val.ok and surrounding it with a try-catch, but I can't seem to figure out how to handle if they are not found.

```
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const web = new WebClient(TOKEN);

exports.myCommand = (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.body.text;
    let message = {"text": ""};

    res.status(200).send("Verifying user...");

    (async () => {
        let val = await web.users.info({user: userId});
        if (!val.ok) {
            message.text = "Error: "+ user +" not found";
        } else {
            message.text = "User: " + user;
        }
    })();
};
```

Am I going about this the right way, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: I wonder what you are trying to do. Every user sending you a slash command will always be part of the users list by default. So this seams to be redundant.

Comment: The command itself requires another user as a parameter. Ex: "/myCommand @user" Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: In general the API will send a response that will contain a property `error` with the text `user_not_found` if the user does not exist. However, if you get the user from a mention in the slash command response it can ONLY contain users from that workspace. so again I am not sure what you are trying to do? can you please explain what your goal is here?

Comment: And a tip: if you turn on escaping for your slash command in Slack `text` will include the user with its ID, so a @user will be translated to `<@U12345678|user>'

Comment: You're right, I have no idea why I didn't think that. I've been over-complicating it for no reason. I want the command to add the user to a text file along with some other information, so I wanted to verify that they existed.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if you still need anything - would be great if we could come to a solution for this question somehow.